# this.props.createTask is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I am following this tutorial [React Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IR6smI_YJDE&t=123s)

Here is the thing:
I am calling function **createTask** from create-todo.js; 
the function is defined in app.js

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ToDosList from './todos-list';
import CreateToDoItem from './create-todo-item'

const todoitems=[
{
    task: 'finish react todo tutorial',
    isCompleted: false 
},

 {
    task: 'eat lunch',
    isCompleted: true 
 }
];


export default class App extends React.Component 
{
   constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state={
            todoitems
        };
}
render()
{
    return(
            <div>
                <h1>React Demo App - ToDos </h1>
                <CreateToDoItem  createtask ={this.createTask.bind(this)}/>
                <ToDosList 
                todoitems={this.state.todoitems}
                />
            </div>
    );
 }

createTask(task)
{   
    //alert('called');
    this.state.todoitems.push({
        task,
        isCompleted:false
    });
    this.setState({todoitems: this.state.todoitems});
  }
}
```

create-todo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './app';

export default class CreateToDoItem extends React.Component 
{
render()
{
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleCreate.bind(this)}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="what do I need to do?" ref="createInput"/>
            <button>Create</button>
        </form>
    );
}

handleCreate(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    //alert('called');
    this.props.createTask(this.refs.createInput.value); //this throws error
 }
}
```

I am absolutely new to React.js. I don't know how this works. Should the function be available to create-todo.js? The code is exactly how it is shown in the tutorial.

Comment: **typo**, use `createtask` not `createTask`, like this: `this.props.createtask()` because you are passing the function in `props` by key `createtask` and the actual function name is `createTask`.

Comment: Thanks bhai...! Put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is, you are passing the `function` in `props` by a different key and using inside child by a different key.

Actual function name: `createTask`

Passing in props by key: `createtask`

Using inside child by: `createTask`

so use `this.props.createtask()` instead of `this.props.createTask()`

Answer (score 0):

Your prop is named "createtask". You should probably change your prop name to createTask (as opposed to changing references to this.props.createtask).

Answer (score 0):

**You could do like this:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ToDosList from './todos-list';
import CreateToDoItem from './create-todo-item'

const items = [
  {
    task: 'finish react todo tutorial',
    isCompleted: false
  },

  {
    task: 'eat lunch',
    isCompleted: true
  }
];


export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      todoitems: items,
      taskItem: ''
     }


  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      taskItem: e.target.value
    })
  }


  handleCreate = () => {
    e.preventDefault()

    item = {
      task: taskItem,
      isCompleted: false // default value
    }

    this.setState({
      todoitems: [...this.state.todoitems, item ]
    })
  } 


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Demo App - ToDos </h1>
        <CreateToDoItem
         handleChange={this.handleChange}
         handleCreate={this.handleCreate}
         taskItem={this.state.taskItem}
          />
        <ToDosList todoitems={this.state.todoitems}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Then your form will be:**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './app';

    export const CreateToDoItem = (props) => (
            <form onSubmit={props.handleCreate}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="what do I need to do?"
                 onChange={props.handleChange}
                 value={props.taskItem} />
                <button type='submit'>Create</button>
            </form>
    );
```

I hope it help you :)

Kindly,